# Trouble parsing JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to parse JSON that looks like this:

`{ "values" : [{ "alpha":8 },{ "beta":4 },{ "gamma":-3 } ]}`

I'm parsing it with: `console.log(msg.values.alpha)`, and get:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined
```

This is how I have seen done it on other sites. Doing it with `console.log(msg.values)` returns `undefined`, and just running console.log(msg) returns proper `JSON`. I have seen other people with this issue, but nothing that is said to do is working. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running `JSON.parse(msg)`?

Comment: No, apparently that is for parsing non JSON text into JSON. @KailanBlanks Is that incorrect? If so what's the syntax?

Comment: Assuming that msg is a String with JSON, `data = JSON.parse(msg)` will parse it into an object. Then you will have to follow what t3dodson said in his answer.

Comment: So like `data = JSON.parse(msg); console.log(data.values[0].alpha);`?

Comment: That would be correct :)

Comment: I'm getting this again: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token C`

Comment: Are you sure the JSON you are parsing is valid?

Comment: most errors in nodejs are due to to scope , confirm that the JSON object has existence before you output it's value . try to check it's length , I guess it has not loaded or some reason like that .

Comment: maybe post your full code so that we can help better

Comment: Yes, it's valid. @KailanBlanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/skylerspaeth/87b01b462a3dcd18f44c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to parse it to an object using `JSON.parse`

`msg.values` is an array. Technically you would have to access it via `msg.values[0].alpha.`

## Better solution.

if you are using underscore `npm install underscore`

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var msg = JSON.parse('{ "values" : [{ "alpha":8 },{ "beta":4 },{ "gamma":-3 } ]}');
var alpha = _.find(msg.values, function (value) {
    return value.hasOwnProperty('alpha');
}).alpha;
```

The underscore solution would allow you to not rely on the order of the array so its probably better style.

---

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h1syetc7/) is a fiddle of my code running in a browser.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth Please see my update. The snippet I have works if you install underscore.

Comment: Ok, I will.     Character limit :(

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token C`.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth is the JSON you posted in your question the exact same as you tried? I've ran this locally and it worked. I'm making a fiddle right now.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth I've added a link to a fiddle of the above code.

Comment: Ok, my JSON is changing every 1/8 of a second, coming live from a gyroscope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99504/discussion-between-t3dodson-and-skyler-spaeth).

Comment: I'm trying, I think the issue was how I was printing it, so I'm trying to debug.

Comment: I tried it too, and it works fine, I think the issue is once I feed it a changing variable, it gets confused. Thanks!